# MySQL Case Statement with LIKE for string

Tags: mysql, case, sql-like

I have a table with an existing `user_agent` column that I want to make a new column based on if user agent contains the substrings `'windows'` or `'os x'` in MySQL and I can't figure out what is wrong or find examples of case statements with `LIKE` for strings on this site. My version of `MySQL` is `8.0.26`.

```
SELECT user_id, 
    CASE user_agent 
    WHEN LIKE '%windows%' THEN 'Windows'
    WHEN LIKE '%OS X%' THEN 'Mac'
    Else 'Other'
    END AS Operating System

    FROM pageviews;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, 
    CASE 
    WHEN user_agent  LIKE '%windows%' THEN 'Windows'
    WHEN user_agent  LIKE '%OS X%' THEN 'Mac'
    Else 'Other'
    END AS  `Operating System` 

    FROM pageviews;
```

Comment: Yep, that's the correct syntax. For alias names, though, you should use standard double quotes or MySQL's proprietary backticks. Don't use single quotes. They are meant for string literals and using them for names instead can lead to unexpected and undesired results sometimes.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks! just update my answer after your comment.